# Ifstream in c++

Tags: c++, ifstream

I need some help with a code.

I need to take this information to my c++ code from another file, the last one is just like this:

`Human:3137161264 46`

This is what I wrote for it, it takes the word "Human" correctly but then it takes random numbers, not the ones written on the file I just wrote:

```
struct TSpecie {
string id;
int sizeGen;
int numCs; };
```

__

```
TSpecie readFile(string file){
TSpecie a;
ifstream in(file);
if (in){
    getline(in,a.id,':');
    in >> a.sizeGen;
    in >> a.numCs;
}
else
    cout << "File not found";
return a; }
```

Hope you can solve it and thanks for your help

Comment: `3137161264` causes integer overflow leading to *Undefined Behaviour*

Comment: You can do things like `if (!(in >> a.sizeGen)){std::cout << "failed reading sizeGen\n";}` to check if reading the number succeeded.

Answer (score 2):

`3137161264` causes integer overflow leading to *Undefined Behaviour*.

So `unsigned int sizeGen` would be enough for this case, but consider `long long (unsigned) int sizeGen` too.

**Edit 1:** As pointed out by @nwp in comments to your question, you can also check your stream if any error has occured:

```
//read something and then 

if (!in) { 
    // error occured during last reading 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Always** test whether input was successful *after* reading from the stream:

```
if (std::getline(in, a.id, ':') >> a.sizeGen >> a.NumCs) {
   // ...
}
```

Most likely the input just failed. For example, the first number probably can't be read successful. Also note that `std::getline()` is an *unformatted input function*, i.e., it won't skip leading whitespace. For example the newline after the last number read is still in the stream (at least, since your use of `std::getline()` finishes on a colon, it will only create an odd ID).